# Pass references by value Java

Tags: java, function, reference

I have the following code:

```
public class PassReferenceByValue {


    static void modify(String m)
    {
       m = "Else";
    }


    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
       String actual = "Something";

       modify(actual);

       System.out.println(actual);

    }
}
```

It will print `Something`.

I get that Java doesn't pass objects at all. Instead, it creates copy of the reference passed. If i understood correctly, when I call `modify(actual)` Java creates another reference to the same object. So, now we have two references that reference to the object `actual`. Now, through the second reference, we modify the object and the object should change. The object `actual` should change, because through the copied reference we have the same access to the object.

Can somebody explain me where I fail to understand the concept of passing references by value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: (And look at the various other related questions on the right.)

Comment: m = "Else"; don't modify any object. It create a new string object which contains the string "Else" and then change m to reference this new object.

Comment: Disagree with the duplicate inasmuch as answers to the referenced question do not clear up the questioner's point of confusion. Might be better to edit the question so it's asking "Does String reassignment change the underlying object, or create a new String and assign the reference to it?"

Comment: @Want check out [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1431684/javatemp.png) out. It should clear your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void modify(String m)
    {
       m = "Else";
       System.out.println(m);
    }
```

If you do this m will print Else, it is only the local variable m what is getting assigned to a new value. value of actual in the main method is not getting changed here.

Comment: Do comment before negative voting.

Answer (score 0):

All "variables" in Java are references to address in a memory when the object resides.

So you have:

```
actual -> String("Something")
```

after method invocation you have

```
actual -> String("Something")
```

and

```
m -> String("Something")
```

You are just changing `m -> String("Else")`

bot not `actual -> String("Something")`

Where `String("...")` notation means object String with value "...".

Comment: Also, as soon as you leave `modify()` the variable `m` has gone out of scope and so neither it nor the String it references can be used.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

Java's pass by value and pass by reference is nicely explained

Answer (score 0):

1. Strings are immutable, but that's a different discussion
2. You are not modifying the "object" pointed by String reference `actual`. In the method `modify()` you are just **overwriting** the reference to point to a **new String** object called `"Else"`. Now this **doesn't** make *any "effect"* to the object pointed by `actual`. Hence when you print `actual`, it still remains the same

Why I am trying to make point 1 is, say your `modify` method was like below

```
public void modify(String s) {
   s.replaceAll("Some", "Many");
}
```

Still the `actual` would have printed `"Something"` because of `String`'s **immutable** behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing `m` which is a local variable only visible within `modify()` referencing an object. You're creating a new String object with the value "Else" and making `m` point towards it.

When you then come out of `modify()` and print `actual`, it is still a reference to the String object containing the text "Something".